# What control is this?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want to make a button like this:
[image]

The **first image is a normal button**, but the **second is a button with mouseEnter event fired**. The bottom part of the button in the second image is not clickable and it acts like a tool tip. How can I make this kind of a button? Do I need to use a tool tip? Please give me some code examples.

**EDIT:**

Here's F Ruffel's code which I modified:

```
<HeaderedContentControl BorderBrush="Black">
                <HeaderedContentControl.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Header Placeholder" Margin="5" />
                </HeaderedContentControl.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Content Placeholder Line 1" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Content Placeholder Line 2" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Content Placeholder Line 3" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <HeaderedContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition />
                                            <RowDefinition />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Border x:Name="headerBorder" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                            <Grid Name="Header">
                                                <Rectangle Fill="White"/>
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Border x:Name="contentBorder" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                            <ContentPresenter />
                                        </Border>
                                        <Border x:Name="cutOutBorder" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger SourceName="Header" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="headerBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                                            <Setter TargetName="contentBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,1,1" />
                                            <Setter TargetName="contentBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                            <Setter TargetName="cutOutBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        </Trigger>                                      
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </HeaderedContentControl.Style>

            </HeaderedContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

Now the last problem is: the expanded part pushes all controls down, and that's what I don't   want. Please modify this code to make the extended part overlay controls that are below it, just like in the image.

Comment: do you want your button like that when your mouse enter? all the surface should be clickable?

Comment: No the bottom part of the button should be like a tool tip, meaning when mouse leaves the upper part of the button the bottom part disappears.

Comment: I don't understand, tooltip it doesn't enough? you can eventually use a simple panel how appears when your mouse enter the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I like about WPF is that there is a hundred and one ways to do the same thing. In addition to the suggestions above, you could easily style a `HeaderedContentControl` to give the desired look and behaviour:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <HeaderedContentControl BorderBrush="Black">
            <HeaderedContentControl.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Header Placeholder" Margin="5" />
            </HeaderedContentControl.Header>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Content Placeholder Line 1" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Content Placeholder Line 2" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Content Placeholder Line 3" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <HeaderedContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
                                <Grid x:Name="outerGrid" Background="Transparent">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition />
                                            <RowDefinition />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Border x:Name="headerBorder" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Border x:Name="contentBorder" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                            <ContentPresenter />
                                        </Border>
                                        <Border x:Name="cutOutBorder" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Transparent" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUp" SourceName="contentPresenter">
                                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="makeVisibleBeginStoryboard">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="headerBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <Thickness Left="1" Top="1" Right="1" Bottom="0" />
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <Thickness Left="1" Top="0" Right="1" Bottom="1" />
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="cutOutBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave" SourceName="outerGrid">
                                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="makeVisibleBeginStoryboard" />
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter" SourceName="cutOutBorder">
                                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="makeVisibleBeginStoryboard" />
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </HeaderedContentControl.Style>
        </HeaderedContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This solution simulates a cut-out portion (which is just a cell in a `Grid`). It uses an `EventTrigger` so that content is visible when the `Header` is clicked, and content is made invisible when the mouse leaves the `Grid` hosting the content, or if it enters the cut-out portion.

Although I think this achieves what you are after, I would recommend investigating other approaches like `ToolTip`, `Adorner`, or a even custom control. Using animations like this always feels like over-kill to me :)

Comment: I like your answer, but it seems like the mouseOver event fires only when the mouse is over the text "Header Placeholder". If you can fix that I will accept your answer.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for. If you want it so that the expanded part stays open after the header part is clicked, then I would suggest changing the ContentPresenter to a ToggleButton, and then have the Trigger check the IsChecked property.

Comment: I mean the MouseOver event triggers only when the mouse is over the text of the header, but I want it to trigger when it's over any part of the non-expanded part of the button.

Comment: Sure, although I would suggest you start a new question rather than us constantly modifying the original question and answer since your new question is a more general layout question (e.g. applies to any expanding control, such as an Expander). Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to add an adorner to your button and make it visible on Mouse Enter event and just remove the adorner on Mouse Leave event. In case you are new to Adorner's you can look at the brief overview here and few custom samples here-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx

http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/wpf-simple-adorner-usage-with-drag-and-resize-operations/

Answer (score 0):

This could be an [Expander](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.aspx) styled appropriately. [Here](http://wpftutorial.net/Expander.html) is an image how it normally looks like, but with templates and styles you can drastically alter the appearance of controls. The behaviour looks like an expander that just expands on hover instead of click, though.

Comment: I've updated the question. I need the button to look like the second image when button mouseEnter event fires.

Comment: Just expand the expander when the mouse enters. You *can* fine-tune behaviour of controls, you know.

Answer (score -2):

I've got a small example that I build myself once. In CSS set `#loginBox` to `display:none`. Then when `a.loginButton` is clicked, let javascript (e.g. jQuery) change display to `display:block`

```
<div id="head-login">
            <a href="#" id="loginButton"><span>Klanten login</span></a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div id="loginBox">                
                    <form id="loginForm" action="http://www.dennishunink.nl/dqr/app/login-check.php" method="post">
                        <fieldset id="body">
                            <fieldset>
                                <label for="email">Email Adres</label>
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                                <label for="password">Wachtwoord</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
                            </fieldset>
                            <input type="submit" id="login" value="Log in" />
                            <label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />Onthoudt mij</label>
                        </fieldset>
                        <span><a href="#">Wachtwoord vergeten?</a></span>
                    </form>
                </div>
         </div>



     </div>
```

Comment: How to use this with a WPF application?

Comment: Good one. Guess i totally overlooked the wpf part; this is pretty straight forward php/css. But as far as my knowledge about wpf goes, you can't use it one on one. But it might give you a clou about the ways you should search for the answer. Just add another part, make it invincible until the button has been clicked. Sorry can't help you out :(